# HighCharts / Wordpress - How do I generate unique charts for ~4,800 posts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, highcharts

Relatively new to HighCharts, PHP and JS but continuing to learn. I have searched extensively on the web but have not found anything that works so far.

I have a listing website that displays information on a variety of hospitals. As part of this offering, I am looking to show salary information unique to each hospital (~4,800) in HighCharts, using the WP post ID as the identifier.

I have a static chart showing across all hospitals as a placeholder right now but would like make this dynamic based on the individual hospital in question. I tried to use an Ajax POST command to push the right data without any luck thus far.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Code below:

JS Chart Display (Contained in a Widget)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>
```

```
*** Function does not work when included ***
//var post_id = parseInt( ( document.body.className.match( /(?:^|\s)postid-([0-9]+)(?:\s|$)/ ) || [ 0, 0 ] )[1] ); // - JS to get post ID
var post_id = "1"; //Temporary post_id

    jQuery(function($){
            $('.section').click(function () {
               jQuery.ajax({
                    url: http://www.rndeer.com/data.php,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: post_id,
                    success:function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });     
            });  
        });

***********************
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            colors: ['#0000FF', '#0066FF', '#3396d1'],
            title: {
                text: '<?php echo get_the_title();?>',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Salary ($ per / hour)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#3396d1'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': $'+ this.y+' per / hour';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Data.PHP Script

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Database_Name","Password");


if (!$con) {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

//$post_id = $_POST['post_id']; - Attempt at getting posted data


$post_id = '1';


mysql_select_db("Database Name", $con);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT hospital, newgrad, median, high FROM salary_estimates WHERE id='".$post_id."'");



$category = array();

$category['name'] = 'Hospital';


$series1 = array();

$series1['name'] = 'New Grad';


$series2 = array();

$series2['name'] = 'Median';


$series3 = array();

$series3['name'] = 'High';


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$category['data'][] = $r['hospital'];
$series1['data'][] = $r['newgrad'];
$series2['data'][] = $r['median'];
$series3['data'][] = $r['high'];   

}


$result = array();

array_push($result,$category);

array_push($result,$series1);

array_push($result,$series2);

array_push($result,$series3);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Could you post your json response data here ? from which you are suppose to create your series?

Comment: JSON data is a follows: [{"name":"Hospital","data":["UVA"]},{"name":"New Grad","data":[40]},{"name":"Median","data":[50]},{"name":"High","data":[70]}]

Comment: its working , see here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/CPT6d/81/ .

Comment: Did you observe any js error in error console of browser ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I apologize for any confusion. I am able to get the chart to display, though I cannot get it to be customized for each unique hospital. As above near the *'s - I am looking to POST a variable through to pull the right JSON data back into the graph. I am running into issues either posting or receiving the information as the connection is not taking place!

Comment: Just one more recommendation here : use same ready function for jquery . I mean either $(function(){}) of Jquery(function ) keep its same .... Second is put your chart in success function of Ajax call . Please see your network-xhr tab in browser console (chrome-mozilla) to see if the call return with success or there is any issue with the call

Comment: The simplest way to apply this scenario in Wordpress, is prepare separate template (php file) with requested DIV (unique ID) and javascript code. Have you tried that?

Comment: Do you "see" the post_id sent in the header from the browser? If the post_id is the Wordpress one and you have it mapped then you can grab the post id on the server side in PHP - get_the_ID()